Weighted Clustering
I have a dataframe with county-level socioeconomic variables of the USA. Additionally, I have a column with the corresponding Coefficients of Variation (CV) for each variable.



County
Var1
CV Var1
Var2
CV Var2




A
3
24
45
21


B
6
18
34
18



I want to cluster the counties based on their socioeconomic conditions. As the data quality varies in different counties (this is measured by the CV), I thought it would be interesting, to give more more weight to those counties which have a lower CV (meaning a higher data quality) in the clustering process.
I tried using sk-learns weighted k-means clustering. Similar to this example:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    "Variable1": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    "Variable2": [5, 15, 25, 35, 45],
    "CV_Variable1": [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2],  # Coefficients of Variation
    "CV_Variable2": [0.05, 0.15, 0.05, 0.25, 0.15]  # Coefficients of Variation
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Extract variables and weights
variables = ["Variable1", "Variable2"]
weights = df[["CV_Variable1", "CV_Variable2"]].values

# Normalize the data
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df[variables])

# Perform K-Means clustering
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, max_iter=1000)
kmeans.fit(X_scaled, sample_weight=weights)
df['Cluster'] = kmeans.labels_

# Print cluster centroids
print("Cluster Centroids:")
print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

# Plot the K-Means results
plt.scatter(df['Variable1'], df['Variable2'], c=df['Cluster'], cmap='viridis')
plt.xlabel('Variable1')
plt.ylabel('Variable2')
plt.title('K-Means Clustering of Toy Data')
plt.colorbar(label='Cluster')
plt.show()


But I get ValueError: Sample weights must be 1D array or scalar. Is there any work-around or other Clustering algorithm which makes it work to assign a weight to each variable value for each county?
I'm happy for any advise or guidance. Thanks!

just sum your CV columns into a single columns weight for example. It will give you a score representing over all data quality of the country/sample. Be careful though that in your case if a lower CV indicates a better data quality then you should use 1/w and not directly the weight vector.
